# ACDC Hat for Raspberry pi

Tags: power-supply

I though of designing a HAT (additional snap-in board) for Raspberry Pi that has ACDC power converter, 5V protection and a super-capacitor for short power drop solution on it.

Why? Maybe it is a bit more elegant than having 2 units, IMHO.

Is there a reason why I should NOT do it? There are many different Hats around but none are for ACDC power supply.

1. The parts are all good quality and made of existing ACDC modules.
2. The boards will be placed in a sealed plastic box and will be located in locations out of reach.

Although this is for the RPi the same question can be for Arduino or other development boards or SOMs

Comment: One can do AC to DC conversion with a couple of diodes, perhaps you mean a Mains (110V - 240 V AC) to 5 V DC mains adapter ? Like the circuit in a phone's power adapter (what many people call a charger which it is not).

Comment: Please read http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on bringing mains voltage (110, 230) to a Hat, Id suggest this is not a good idea. These are dangerous voltages for product destined to be used by hobby and potentially un-trained consumers.

If you wanted to do this and sell the HAT, you would have to pass standards body approval processes where you want to sell it. It's not just a case of putting it in a box.

This potential hazard is why most hobby/DIY product is based on the use of Wallwarts (which are approved products). I suggest you make your product for this type of power supply (you can get transformers in Wallwart sizes so if you really want to feed (low voltage) AC to the board you can).